# How to fix Invalid or unexpected token issue when running "ionic cordova build android" command?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to generate an APK of my ionic applications. ionic serve render without errors, but when i run `ionic cordova build android` it give me this error :

i've already try to uninstall then install cordova without results.

```
C:\Users\Nacim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\currently-unhandled\core.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nacim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\currently-unhandled\index.js:2:12)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova build android --verbose exited with exit code 1.
```

Any idea of the root of the issue ?

Comment: did you try `ionic cordova run android`

Comment: Yes, and the same error occur @SudarshanaDayananda

Comment: try `cordova clean` command and then `ionic cordova run android` command

Comment: cordova clean lead to the same error @SudarshanaDayananda

Answer (score 0):

Uninstaling then instaling ionic and cordova resolve the issue. It was caused by some missing dependancies in cordova and ionic package due to poor internet connexion.